# How to parse a u' prefixed JSON response in Android

Tags: android, json, unicode

I'm trying to parse a JSON response, but all the fields are u' prefixed. I did some search its Unicode format, not UTF-8 realised, but how to parse it finally in Android?

```
"{u'response': [{u'status': u'ONGOING', u'challenge_type': u'Monthly Challenges', and so on
```

Online JSON Viewer is formatting it but since it's Unicode, so all are chars, that's not the way we can parse JSON response.

In my code even creating a JSONObject is also throwing an exception.

Any solution or hint towards correct path would be very helpful.

[JSON link](https://www.hackerearth.com/api/events/upcoming/?format=json)

For those who are giving a downvote please leave a solution before the downvote, would really like to know what I missed out.

Comment: do you see this in your **real data** (i.e. API's response) or in logcat/console or python output etc?

Comment: In browser whenever I open the API. Same in the OKHttp response string using logcat/debug.

Answer (score 2):

That is not JSON. That's a Python dict literal. Although Python and JS literals are superficially similar they are far from cross-compatible.

You could parse it from Python using `ast.literal_eval`, but that's not much use from Android, and it would be a very strange web API that chooses Python literals for its output format. If you have a web service that is supposed to be returning JSON but is actually returning this, it's broken.